# adjust values in numpy array based on coefficients

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using a threshold vector to create binary values in a 2d numpy array row-wise. Sample code is provided below:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(100000, 200)
coef = np.random.random(x.shape[1])
x = np.array([[1 if x[i,j]>=coef[j] else 0 for j in range(x.shape[1])] for i in range(x.shape[0])])
```

Is there anyway to make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the comparison with `coef` to give us a boolean array and then convert to `int` array, thus leveraging vectorized capabilities of NumPy -

```
x_out = (x >= coef).astype(int)
```